# What is the fastest way to 'print' to file in perl?

Tags: perl, buffer

I've been writing output from perl scripts to files for some time using code as below:

```
open( OUTPUT, ">:utf8", $output_file ) or die "Can't write new file: $!";

print OUTPUT "First line I want printed\n";
print OUTPUT "Another line I want printing\n";

close(OUTPUT);
```

This works, and is faster than my initial approach which used "say" instead of print (Thank you NYTProf for enlightening my to that!)

However, my current script is looping over hundreds of thousands of lines and is taking many hours to run using this method and NYTProf is pointing the finger at my thousands of 'print' commands. So, the question is... **Is there a faster way of doing this?**

Other Info that's possibly relevant...
Perl Version: 5.14.2 (On Ubuntu)

Background of the script in question...
A number of '|' delimited flat files are being read into hashes, each file has some sort of primary key matching entries from one to another. I'm manipulating this data and them combining them into one file for import into another system.

The output file is around 3 Million lines, and the program starts to noticeably slow down after writing around 30,000 lines to said file.  (A little reading around seemed to point towards running out of write buffer in other languages but I couldn't find anything about this with regard to perl?)

**EDIT:** I've now tried adding the line below, just after the open() statement, to disable print buffering, but the program still slows around the 30,000th line.

```
OUTPUT->autoflush(1);
```

Comment: `autoflush` will slow down your output rather than speeding it up. It forces data to be written to the disk at every `print` statement instead of waiting for the IO buffer to fill. What makes you think the problem is the speed of the output? I think it is more likely to be the work being done in preparing the data. I suggest you try disabling the print statements and see how your program performs with no output going on.

Comment: Try syswrite(OUTPUT, "..."); . It's faster than print statements for STDOUT.

Comment: @Nick: `syswrite` on its own, without any user-coded buffering, will have a similar effect to `autoflush` and force a disk write on every record. Writing a home-brewed output buffering system to use together with `syswrite` seems unlikely to speed things up, but I guess it's possible.

Comment: @Ashimema You are almost certainly focusing on the wrong thing. Consider your algorithm, data structures, and memory usage. The slowness probably resides there rather than in Perl's ability to write to a file efficiently.

Comment: Is this really Unicode data, or is it just ASCII?

Comment: Cheers for all the comments guys, I'm going back through the profiler to check for other slow points as suggested and will have a rethink regarding the algorithm.

Comment: Unicode data, yeah, unfortunately it is.. full of strange characters so is exported as Unicode from source.

Comment: Are you sure you're not leaking memory per iteration through some circularly referenced data structure (for example), some buggy XS code, some buggy call to an external library, etc... or doing more work per iteration due to how an algorithm is constructed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to redesign the algorithm your program uses. File output speed isn't influenced by the amount of data that has been output, and it is far more likely that your program is reading and processing data but not releasing it.

- Check the amount of memory used by your process to see if it increases inexorably
- Beware of `for (<$filehandle>)` loops, which read whole files into memory at once
- As I said in my comment, disable the relevant `print` statements to see how performance changes

Comment: This is good advice.  Perl shouldn't care whether you're on line 1 or 100,000,000 of your output.  A significant slowdown after awhile sounds a lot like swamping RAM and getting into virtual ram (ie, swapping to the hard drive).  Look for objects not being destroyed, circular references, variables accumulating longer and longer strings, etc.

Comment: Hmm, the memory usage of the process doesn't appear to increase inexorably, so I don't think it's that that is the problem.  I am using the Text::CSV::Encoded module to parse the files into hashes though and that does appear to be another bottleneck.  As for disabling the print statements, your right disabling them made little impact on the overall runtime of the program so although NYTProf claimed 'print' as being one of the longest operations, I'm thinking I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @Ashimema: Disk output will always take many thousands of times longer than most processing. What does the profiler say once you have removed the output statement? Do you want to show your program so that I can take a look? We can do it off-list if you like.

Comment: @Borodin: I ended up heavily refactoring the script a few years ago now and have vastly improved in my perl programming generally to boot. But thanks for the offer all these years later ;)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to concat all the single print's into a single scalar and then print scalar all at once?  I have a script that outputs an average of 20 lines of text for each input line.  When using individual print statements, even sending the output to /dev/null, took a long time.  But when I packed all the output (for a single input line) together, using things like:

`$output .= "...";
$output .= sprintf("%s...", $var);`

Then just before leaving the line processing sub-routine, I 'print $output'.  Printing all the lines at once.  The number of calls to print went from ~7.7M to about 386K - equal to the number of lines in the input date file.  This shaved about 10% off of my total execution time.

Comment: As a non-Perl comment, if you substituted $output as the first variable, it may speed up again (instead of .= )  It does in Java and JS; due to templates I have not done this in Perl yet.